# How do I change buffer data with std::vector?

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

So my idea is to add more data to the buffer.
My first idea was to use std::vector so I have a non fixed array, that I can add data to.
In the generation of the data:

```
    void initData()
{
    std::vector<float> vertices;
    
    std::array<float, 12> verts = {
         0.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f,  0.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  0.0f
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++)
        vertices.push_back(verts[i]);
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], GL_DYBAMIC_DRAW);
    
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

this works just fine!
but then when I want to add more data:

```
void render()
{
    std::vector<float> newVertices;
    
    // Generates new vertices with more data, like I did in the initData()
    // for-loop adding it to the new vector (newVertices)
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, newVertices.size() * sizeof(newVertices), &newVertices[0]);
    
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE, 0, 6 * theAmountIveGeneratedBefore);
}
```

that's the part that I can't seem to get to work...
what am I doing wrong??

Comment: `vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices)` makes no sense (same goes for the newVertices versaion in the second case)

Comment: [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) updates a subset of a buffer object's data store. It doesn't change the size of the buffer. If you need a buffer with greater size you have to create a new buffer by [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml)

Comment: maybe you meant `vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0])` ? if the intent is the size in bytes of storage of the vector content?

Comment: `vertices.size() * sizeof(*newVertices.data())` or `vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0])`

Comment: Unrelated: Making an `array` of values and then pushing them into the `vector` seems an odd choice. Any reason you can't  construct the `vector` with the values already in it? For example, `std::vector<float> vertices = {0.0f,  0.0f, ...};`

Comment: the reason I am using a "non-fixed" array, as std::vector. Is simply cause I want to have loads of data of multiple rectangles that I don't know exactly how many, therefore I have to generate them without knowing how many

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT:* As pointed out in the comments, you can **NOT** add more data to a buffer using `glBufferSubData()`. So this answer only points out the mistake in calculating the size of the passed data.

`sizeof(newVertices)` doesn't give you what you need. The `std::vector` is a class and is more complicated than a simple array. Also, you don't need its whole size, actually. What you need is actually just the size of a `float`, since you are multiplying it by the number of elements. So just:

```
newVertices.size() * sizeof(float)
```

or

```
newVertices.size() * sizeof(newVertices[0])
```

Comment: That too, but I suppose the new vertices are the same number, that is, I believe he is trying to replace them...

Comment: ah, so what I am getting at, is I shouldn't use "glBufferSubData", but use glBufferData to the bigger data I want to add??

Comment: Yes. You can re-fill the same buffer using `glBufferData()`. Then the buffer is overwritten with the new data and resized, if needed.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev The buffer is not overwritten. A new buffer object is generated and new data store is allocated.